# python name mangling in __init__ seems inconsistent

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a subclass that enhances instead of overriding the base class. I'm using the `super` method to call the base class. I find that I need to use the name mangling feature in `__init__` (but only in init?) to make the code work. So for the heck of it I made the this print example. Since I didn't use name mangling I expected it to call subclass twice when I did the init, instead it calls the base class

It seems that `__init__` sometimes sees the base class and sometimes sees the subclass. I'm sure it's just an incomplete understanding on my part, but was do I need name mangling for the real code, when in the print example it calls the base and subclass just fine?

the code

```
class base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.print()

    def print(self):
        print("base")

class subclass(base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(subclass, self).__init__()
        self.print()

    def print(self):
        super(subclass, self).print()
        print("subclass")

x = base()
x.print()
print("--")
y = subclass()
y.print()
```

the output - why doesn't `y = subclass()` print `subclass` instead of `base` since I didn't use name mangling?

```
> ./y.py 
base
base
-- 
base
subclass
base
subclass
base  
subclass
```

broken code when I don't use name mangling, works when I use `self.__set` and `__set = set` (the commented code). It gets the following error when I don't use `__set`:

```
File "./x.py", line 5, in __init__
   self.set(arg)
TypeError: set() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg2'
```

the code:

```
class base:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.set(arg)
        # self.__set(arg)

    # __set = set

    def set(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

    def print(self):
        print("base",self.arg)

class subclass(base):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        super(subclass, self).__init__(arg1)
        self.set(arg1, arg2)

    def set(self, arg1, arg2):
        super(subclass, self).set(arg1)
        self.arg2 = arg2

    def print(self):
        super(subclass, self).print()
        print("subclass", self.arg2, self.arg)

x = base(1)

x.print()
x.set(11)
x.print()

y = subclass(2,3)

y.print()
y.set(4,5)
y.print()
```

======= update =======

I rewrote the code to look like this:

```
class base:
    def __init__(self):
        print("base init")
        self.print()

    def print(self):
        print("base print")

class subclass(base):
    def __init__(self):
        print("sc init")
        super(subclass, self).__init__()
        print("sc after super")
        self.print()

    def print(self):
        print("subclass print start")
        super(subclass, self).print()
        print("subclass print")

y = subclass()
print("--")
y.print()
```

when I run I get this output:

```
sc init
base init
subclass print start <<<< why is the subclass print called here
base print
subclass print
sc after super
subclass print start
base print
subclass print
--
subclass print start
base print
subclass print
```

why does the `self.print` in the base init call the subclass print when I'm initing the subclass? I was expecting that to call the base print. it does call the base print when I call it outside of the init.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subclass `print` explicitly calls the superclass one.  So every time `subclass.print` is called, *both* "base" and "subclass" will be printed.  This happens three times, because you call the `print` method three times: in `subclass.__init__`, in `base.__init__` (which is called by `subclass.__init__`), and in `subclass.print` (which calls the superclass version).

In your "set" example, `subclass.__init__` calls `base.__init__`, which tries to call `self.set` with just one argument.  But since you are instantiating `subclass`, `self.set` is `subclass.set`, which takes two arguments.

It's unclear what you're trying to achieve with these examples.  Your subclass doesn't really need to call `base.__init__`, because all that would do is call `base.set`, and you're already calling that from `subclass.set`.  So even if you succeeded with all your calls, it would result in some methods getting called multiple times, just like with the `print` example.

My impression is that you're getting a bit carried away and trying to have every method call its superclass version.  That's not always a good idea.  If you write a subclass, and it calls a superclass method, you need to make sure that the subclass still provides an interface that's compatible with what the superclass expects.  If it doesn't, you may need to *not* call the superclass method and instead have the subclass incorporate its functionality "inline" (although this may be more risky if other classes out in the world have made assumptions about how the base class works).  The upshot is that you always need to think about what methods call which others; you can't just call every superclass method everywhere and expect that to work.

Comment: I  called both prints to see what would happen. I'm investigating calling the superclass version just to understand the flow. I think you hit on my issue though. the base class had one arg and the subclass had two. When I tried to call the base class via super that method had 2 args and there wasn't a match. I'll have to think about that a moment.  still a little puzzled why name mangling made it work.

Comment: @kdubs: The name mangling made it work because with name mangling, each version of the method is essentially separate, and can't be overridden by a subclass.  So each class will always be calling its own implementation.  But that is usually not what you want, because then subclasses can't override the base class implementation.  The basic problem is that you can't take a method that requires one parameter and override it with one that requires two; any code that was calling it with one will now fail.  (In many cases this could be handled by giving a default value for the second argument.)

Comment: see my update. the call of print in the init function doesn't work the way I expect

Comment: @kdubs: There are many other questions about that on here.  You called `print` on `self`.  That means it will always call the most specific implementation available for that object (in this case, the `subclass` implementation).  Where you call the method *from* makes no difference, only what object you call it *on*.  The method does not "know" that it is being called from inside `base`.  It just knows it's being called on `self`, and `self` is an instance of `subclass`, so `subclass.print` is what's called.